# How can I change to code so my joystick only makes my character change the jump velocity once?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a joystick set up to make my character move around.

```
public Joystick joystick;

 private void Update()
    {
        if (joystick.Horizontal >= .2f)
        {
            horizontalMove = runSpeed;
        }
        else if (joystick.Horizontal <= -0.2f)
        {
            horizontalMove = -runSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            horizontalMove = 0;
        }

        float verticalMove = joystick.Vertical;

        if (verticalMove >= .8f && controller.m_Grounded)
        {
            jump = true;
        }
        else
        {
            jump = false;
        }
    }
```

The vertical part works great, but whenever I jump, it runs the code in the if statement twice. However, if I go into debug mode and do it frame by frame, it only runs the line once. If I let go of my joystick quickly enough, it only runs the line once as well.

I also have a character controller script, which I reference to make the joystick do stuff.

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
```

My Character controller script looks like this

```
public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
    {
        if (knockbackCount <= 0)
        {
            // Move the character by finding the target velocity
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);
            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // If the player should jump...
            if (m_Grounded == true && jump)
            {
                // Add a vertical force to the player.
                m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
                animator.SetTrigger("takeOff");
            }

            if (m_Grounded && move != 0)
            {
                m_CapsuleCollider.sharedMaterial = m_Slippery;
            }
            else
            {
                m_CapsuleCollider.sharedMaterial = m_Rigid;
            }
            if (!m_Grounded)
            {
                m_CapsuleCollider.sharedMaterial = m_Slippery;
                animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
            }
            else
            {
                animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            }
        }
        if (knockFromRight && knockbackCount > 0)
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(-knockback, knockback / 2);
        }
        if (!knockFromRight && knockbackCount > 0)
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(knockback, knockback / 2);
        }
        knockbackCount = -1;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried moving everything to one script, as well as removing the "if m_Grounded == true && jump" line, and adding the force under the joystick line.

Comment: You could add an additional `bool canJump` which is set to `false` when you set `jump = true`. Then it is only re-enabled when the joystick is below a certain threshold (`verticalMove <= 0.1f`) so it maks sure that the User has to release the jump before another one is possible

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!